# Where clause only for a number of columns

Tags: sql, where-clause, clause

I've tried looking at similar questions but couldn't find my exact use case, apologies if this is a duplicate (knowing how big this website is it probably is so sorry!)

I'm completely new to SQL and have managed to put the following together:

```
GPCUST.DISPUTET,
> GPCUSTEXT.FIELD_VALUE WHERE METAFIELD_ID = '11',

> GPCUSTEXT.FIELD_VALUE WHERE METAFIELD_ID = '12',

> GPCUSTEXT.FIELD_VALUE WHERE METAFIELD_ID = '13',

FROM GPCOMP20.GPCUST

LEFT JOIN GPCOMP20.ARCUST ON GPCUST.CUSTNO=ARCUST.CUSTNO

RIGHT JOIN GPCOMP20.GPCUSTEXT ON GPCUST.CUSTNO=GPCUSTEXT.CUSTNO

WHERE GPCUST.COMPANY IS NOT NULL
```

So the 3 WHERE clauses after the 3 columns that are all `GPCUSTEXT.FIELD_VALUE` only apply to that exact column thus bringing in a different piece of data for each. As it stands it's giving me a red error line under the comma behind each clause saying " incorrect syntax near "," " so it must be wrong the way I'm trying to do it.

I'm using Azure Data Studio and our server is Microsoft SQL Query (I believe this makes a difference to the way I code above?).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

***EDIT***

The GPCUSTEXT table looks as follows when searching on one particular CUSTNO:

| custno | field_value | metafield_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | value1 | 11 |
| 12345 | value2 | 12 |
| 12345 | value3 | 13 |

So the result of my query I'm trying to compile should look like below for this same custno:

| custno | disputet | field_value | field_value | field_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 100.00 | value1 | value2 | value3 |

Comment: `case when METAFIELD_ID = '11' then GPCUSTEXT.FIELD_VALUE end as V11` and so on.

Comment: I can't figure out what your intended logic is here.  Please include some sample data which helps to explain your problem.

Comment: I tried this but it's giving a red line under case saying incorrect syntax near 'case'. the line looks as follows: GPCUSTEXT.FIELD_VALUE case when METAFIELD_ID = '11' then GPCUSTEXT.FIELD_VALUE end as V11,

Comment: Maybe just "WHERE METAFIELD_ID BETWEEN 11 AND 13"...difficult to say without sample data and expected result.

Comment: @tim Sure let me show the results of the table I'm trying to pull in

Comment: Just edited my question with the tables, hopefully it makes more sense now

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products have different solutions here.)

Comment: I'm using Azure Data Studio, connection type is Microsoft SQL Server is that the answer you're looking for?